# discord.py Проблема с Intents

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord-api, discord.py

Делаю приватного бота. Пытаюсь пробег по списку администраторов (их id) и если один из **не** оффлайн, **тогда** выбрать его, но вместо этого выдает ошибку:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status'
```

Сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой впервые, но на 80% уверен что это связано с интентами.

Мой код:

```py
intents= 
discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
admins = [664907044033134611, 
696432426293002292, 882334177809285130]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "n.", intents=intents)
client.remove_command("help")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    for adminid in admins:
                    admin = ctx.guild.get_member(adminid)
                    if admin.status.name != "offline":
                        online = True
                        onlineadmin = adminid
                if online:
                    await  ctx.guild.get_member(onlineadmin).send("Вы были выбраны!")
```

На сайте для бота везде поставил галки с интентами, но ничего не поменялось. Есть у кого нибудь решение проблемы, или хотя бы объяснение?

Comment: попробуйте - bot.get_user(int(user_id))         get_member получает пользователя в плане участника сервера

Comment: Попробуйте `discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=member.id)`

Answer (score 1):

лучше загружать сразу все интенты, чтобы не было с ними проблем `discord.Intents.All()`

```
admins = [664907044033134611, 696432426293002292, 882334177809285130]
for adminid in admins:
    admin = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=adminid)
    if admin:
        await admin.send("Вы были выбраны!")
```